# Are large databases efficient in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 550,000 lines of data that I need to put into a sqlite database. I could make one large table with all 550,000 lines of data or I could split this into 12 different table (one for each month of the year). this data is all the same type but I am looking it up by the timestamp.

Basically I am asking would it be more efficient to have 12 tables (one per month) and then when I need to look up data I narrow it down to the month first and search through the corresponding table? Or would it be faster to simply store everything in one massive table and search the entire sql table every single time I need to look up information?

Comment: In general, splitting data into different tables makes a database *less* efficient.  550,000 rows is not particularly large, even for SQLite.

Comment: One big table, with appropriate indexes.

Comment: Half a million rows is not a *large database*, even for SQLite. Fragmenting your data into multiple tables (one per month) is going to make even basic queries vastly more complex, and make it a major headache to retrieve data that spans more than one month (e.g., a quarterly summary of sales). I'd recommend a book or web tutorial on basic database design.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback!